# Explorer.exe regularly displaying very high CPU usage

Tags: windows-10, laptop, cpu, windows-explorer

This one has been bugging me for a while.
Apologies for the long story, I've tried to add as much as I can. Perhaps someone recognises this.

**The problem:**
I'm using Win10 on a Dell domain laptop at home (i7, 32GB), and regularly explorer.exe starts using excessive CPU time (up to 40%), slowing the laptop down severely (and additionally causing the CPU fan to run at a very noisy max speed). This happens when I have a lot of explorer windows open (say, 10+). I've opened many more windows without issue on previous devices (Win10/7/XP), so I'm not quite sure why this suddenly is a problem. It goes away when I close the majority of the windows (sometimes I include a complementary reboot).

Not sure if this is related (if definitely not I'll start a separate question), but **PgUp and PgDn** on the keyboard regularly refuse to operate. If this happens, I have to press them down for a number of seconds for them to spring back into action, after which they work as intended again.

**Attempted fixes:**
So far I've ran SFC /scanall, to no avail, and checked both file system and hardware integrity of the attached drives (1x SATA M2, 2x 2.5" USB HDD), as well as done a memory scan through Dell diagnostics. The latter more to rule it out, than me suspecting memory is the root cause btw. All drivers appear to be the latest, windows updates are automatically applied when released.

As I've had USB power issues with a previous laptop, I was suspecting perhaps problems with too much power being drawn. Connecting my Android phone to an USB3 port for charging also regularly (but not always) induces high CPU usage of explorer.exe.
I've therefore tried an old 180W adapter instead of the 130W one that came with the docking station, and I get the impression this has slightly reduced the occurrence of the above, but not by much. I'm also not sure if this could be an issue in the first place, as most of the open explorer windows tend to be on the on-board M2 drive (and not the attached HDDs).

**Possibly relevant (by association):**
4x disconnected CIFS shares and 4x webdrive shares, VPN intermittently used (when required for work services), HDMI 3.1 cable connected to 4K TV from docking station (used as an extended desktop). Work dir on M2 drive is permanently SUBST'ed as the D-drive. Two Logitech dongles are permanently attached (KB and mouse). WiFi AP is 1m away from device, connection is very stable.

**tl;dr:** what could cause explorer.exe to claim a lot of CPU time over extended periods?

Comment: I forgot to add I've also ran all Dell Command updates, including BIOS, drivers etc.

Comment: Simple answer.  Third party extensions from stuff you installed (probably).  Try [this](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html) to root out what "extra" crap is installed and disable it.

Comment: A shell extension is a binary (dll) that get's loaded into the explorers process space to "extend" the explorer's functionality (like OneDrive).  Lots of them exist.  Most engineers don't know how to write one that doesn't suck.

Comment: Thanks, interesting angle I hadn't explored yet! 320 extensions, at first glance all belonging to sofware I actively use though (although I'm stuck with a uni provided image, and local admin only gets you so far, I have removed some software I don't need)... Is there any way of investigating if any of these 'hang', like Outlook does for its add-ins? I'm also not sure which ones I could disable or remove without impacting the functionality I actually make use of.

Comment: And a related question, I use SysInternals' Process Explorer which gives me a bit more insight in active processes, but explorer.exe is the only one I see heavily using the CPU. Is there any way of checking the activity coming from these shell extensions?

Comment: I am SO HAPPY to hear that you use the process explorer. Using the process explorer, I set the lower window to "Dll view" and first sort by size.. then by path.  That's how >I< root those buggers out.

Comment: Local admin will let you snoop out what is happening through process monitor.  The filters are a PITA but the tool can sniff out anything that isn't in the kernel.

Comment: I've tried procmon a few years ago for a different issue, produces a deluge that I'm not sure I can interpret properly yet...

Comment: explorer.exe dlls: https://i.imgur.com/iv1Oyv4.png - the top ones seem to be from chrome, google drive, video card (intel) and of course microsoft itself.

Comment: You don't need chrome, intel video, or even google drive (if willing to use the browser).  Even some of the MS stuff might not be needed.  Using a tools like autoruns, it is easy enough to toggle on or off to test.  Yes, procmon takes some finesse to get good at isolating things through the filters.

Comment: I've disabled a host of these through ShellExView, let's see how she behaves. I assume disabling them will unload the dlls? Or does this require a reboot?

Comment: It either requires a reboot or restarting the explorer itself.  A secret that very few people know.. ? .. Click on the taskbar to give it focus.  [ALT]+[F4] will bring up the old school shutdown dialog.  Hold down [Ctrl]+[Alt]+[SHIFT] and click [Cancel].  [Ctrl]+[Shift]+[Esc] brings up task manager. File->Run new task  .. explorer.exe.. wella.

Comment: That is a trick I used to use while authoring shell extensions and has been supported since pre-XP days.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas You can Ctrl+Shift+Right Click the taskbar and it appears on the bottom of the context menu.

Comment: @user1644677 ... ???  ...  WOOOOHHHOOOOO!!! Thanks :)

Comment: That's pretty useful, normally I just kill the process... Thanks :)

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas: can I disable all of those shell extensions without causing issues, i.e. also the Microsoft ones? I reckon 80% of those 320 are 'homegrown'. I assume I shouldn't touch the ones labeled "Microsoft® Windows® Operating System" of course.

Comment: Okay, I've re-enabled a few because explorer.exe ended up in an endless restarting loop (for the record: admin cmd and taskkill /im explorer.exe /f), but so far so good. Let's see if it works.

Comment: Use Autoruns. On the Options menu tick Hide Windows Entries. You can also tick Hide Microsoft Entries. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns just look at the Explorer tab.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me of Autoruns! it's specifically windows explorer that's the biggest culprit, but I bet there's more that's slowing this thing down. Will investigate.